# How to interpret specific MTR packet loss data (are these IPs internal or external?)

Tags: networking, router, ping, traceroute

I've been experiencing some pretty bad, but intermittent, packet loss and I'm not sure if I need a new cable modem or router, or whether it's the ISP.

I ran MTR (well, winmtr) as soon as it started occurring tonight (I was playing a game and it became unstable) and I got these results with around 200 packets (I only ran it for a few seconds so as to not dilute the percentages if it stopped dropping packets):

```
Host                                              %Lost Sent| Recd
192.168.0.1                                       0     195 | 195
96.120.89.245                                     9     148 | 136
68.87.227.73                                      6     159 | 150 
68.86.143.37                                      5     167 | 160 
be-224-rar01.pinole.ca.sfba.comcast.net           4     171 | 165 
be-298-ar01.santaclara.ca.sfba.comcast.net        4     171 | 165
be-33651-cr02.sunnyvale.ca.ibone.comcast.net      9     147 | 135
be-11025-cr01.9greatoaks.ca.ibone.comcast.net     7     156 | 146
be-12578-pe04.9greatoaks.ca.ibone.comcast.net     5     167 | 160
66.208.228.6                                      5     163 | 155
one.one.one.one                                   5     163 | 155
```

Now, it seems clear that the be-* addresses are ISP. However, the first few numbers where I was losing 9, 6, 5% respectively: Are those also Comcast or are those internal? I did a lookup and they seem to be owned by comcast, but I honestly don't know enough to make that conclusion (and they look very different from the *clearly* comcast addresses below them).

My interpretation of this is that my PC's 195 pings made it to the router (192.168.0.1) because I received 195 responses, but that the subsequent pings from the router to the external hosts didn't fair as well.

I have some extra confusion because I *assume* that number should get progressively smaller as you go down the list--if I sent 195 pings but only 148 made it to step two, how did 159 make it to step 3, then 167 and even 171 make it beyond that? (Does it send multiples in case of failure? Does it skip steps sometimes?)

Comment: Try running `pathping` as the output is clearer. It separates packet loss at each router from packet loss in the connection between routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the first few numbers where I was losing 9, 6, 5% respectively: Are those also Comcast or are those internal? I did a lookup and they seem to be owned by comcast, but I honestly don't know enough to make that conclusion (and they look very different from the clearly comcast addresses below them).

Internal *to what*? I guess you mean "internal to my LAN", as the ISP's network usually starts immediately beyond the LAN.

But since 192.168.0.1 is your router (whose job is separating LAN from not-LAN), they must be physically beyond it, which means they are not internal to your LAN anymore, which means they have to be part of Comcast's network.

Most likely, Comcast just uses different address ranges for the regional customer connections and the country-wide backbone. They might even be managed by different people, and e.g. the backbone team wanted to set up reverse-DNS for their routers, while others didn't feel the need to.

> I have some extra confusion because I assume that number should get progressively smaller as you go down the list--if I sent 195 pings but only 148 made it to step two, how did 159 make it to step 3, then 167 and even 171 make it beyond that? (Does it send multiples in case of failure? Does it skip steps sometimes?)

I think you're assuming that mtr only sent 195 pings *total*, and that each packet records the entire path it takes. That is not the case – although such a mechanism technically exists, it's never used because it's insufficient for any path longer than 8 hops, and many ISPs even completely block it without realizing.

Instead, traceroute/MTR relies on routers being able to reply with an error message when they get a packet whose TTL (i.e. hop count limit) has *reached zero*, and each probe can only generate a response from a single router.

For example, if you sent a packet with TTL=5, it'll *quietly* go through the first 4 hops and will only produce a response from the router that's 5 hops away. But if that packet (or its response) is lost, it's impossible for MTR to know whether it "made it to step two" or step three or four – all it knows is that it was lost *somewhere* before the 5th hop.

This means that separate probes are sent for each hop, with incrementing TTLs. There were 195 packets sent with TTL=1, *plus* 148 packets sent with TTL=2, *plus* 159 packets with TTL=3, and so forth.

(Based on your results, I think it's safe to assume that packet loss occurs on the connection between your router and the ISP. So counting only packets that went through that link, i.e. excluding the 1st row, in total you sent 1612 packets and received 1527 replies, which is 5.3% loss on average.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this info when I talk to comcast. Not that it'll do any good. They are the only option above 20Mbps at my address. :|